# how to fix codeignter4 Undefined variable: DBDriver at SYSTEMPATH\Commands\Generators\Views\migration.tpl.php:16

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller, migration, database-migration

how to fix create session migration its saying

> Undefined variable: DBDriver  at
> SYSTEMPATH\Commands\Generators\Views\migration.tpl.php:16

```
    enter codnamespace {namespace};

use CodeIgniter\Database\Migration;
class {class} extends Migration
{
    protected $DBGroup = 'default';
    public function up()
    {
        $this->forge->addField([
            'id' => ['type' => 'VARCHAR', 'constraint' => 128, 'null' => false]e here
```

Comment: is this the complete error message?

Comment: yes this is complete error.

Answer (score 0):

use this command
php spark make:migration --session

Comment: use code tags to clearly mark your command snippet